# Template is not visible in backoffice, when created in VS

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

When I create a new template (.cshtml) in the Views folder of my Visual Studio solution it is not showing up in the backoffice.
If I create a template from the backoffice a file is created in the Views folder that I then have to add to VS as a exciting file - why don't the backoffice show the template if I create one from Visual Studio? I've tried rebuilding the project.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in 2 ways:

1. Create your views in umbraco backend. Then go to visual studio and click the "Show All Files" button in solution explore. Find your new views in the Views folder. Right click on each file and choose "Add file to project".
2. Create your views in visual studio as normal. Then go to umbraco backend and create your Templates, and give them the same name as the view in visual studio. (If your template name in umbraco is "Text Page", -your file name should be "TextPage")

As ProNation says, all templates needs a db reference.

Answer (score 1):

Views/templates work differently to some of the other files like scripts and CSS because they require a reference in the database to allow you to associate them with your doctypes.

Comment: I see, so if I do stuff in the developer tab (but in Visual Studio) Im all good? For instance crealte a partial view in visual studio, it will show up in the backoffice (or do I need to create it in the backoffice and add it to my solution afterwards)?

Comment: "do stuff in the developer tab (but in Visual Studio) - not sure I understand as that's contradictory. You have to at some point add template references in Umbraco so to me it make sense to start there then add to Visual Studio. PartialViews on the other hand you can create in Visual Studio and they should appear in the Umbraco UI because they have no direct association with document types.